# Create Wordpress Multisite Instance Programmatically

Tags: multisite, wp-cli

Our CI process sets up everything from scratch, including WordPress, and our WordPress is a multisite instance. Adding a site after the Multisite functionality has been setup is easy to do programatically, but the initial setup seems to need to be done manually.

Is there a way to setup the initial network tables without hitting install on the dashboard, maybe using WP-CLI or a build in method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WP-CLI has a couple of commands to install Multisite (or convert a non-Multisite WP installation to Multisite):

- [`wp core multisite-install`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/core/multisite-install/)
- [`wp core multisite-convert`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/core/multisite-convert/)

Are either of those what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes this is perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Do I have to do a regular wp install before doing the multisite install?

Comment: If you've got a regular installation, you can use `multisite-convert`. If it's a new installation, you can use `multisite-install` and go directly to a multisite insulation.